# Add variable inside document.write()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to embed iframe using javascript but the "referrerpath" variable is not working inside the document.write() I am new to javascript, how to fix it? thanks

```
var referrerpath = document.referrer.replace(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/]+/, '').replace(/#.*/, '').replace(/\?.*/, '');
    document.write("<iframe src='https://example.com/embed/' + referrerpath + style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:400px;'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't closing the string before concatenating it with your variable:

```js
"<iframe src='https://example.com/embed/" + referrerpath + "' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:400px;'></iframe>"
```

You could also use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
`<iframe src='https://example.com/embed/${referrerpath}' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:400px;'></iframe>`
```

Comment: "template string" is also called template literal.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried this and did not work:
document.write(" ' <iframe src='https://example.com/embed/'  ' + referrerpath + ' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:400px;'></iframe> ' ");

Comment: You have to close the string with the same type of quotes that you opened it with... since you started with " you have to use " before you put the referrerpath into the string

Comment: i tried this, but did not work :( here is the code:

Comment: document.write(" "<iframe src='https://example.com/embed/' "  + referrerpath +  " style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:400px;'></iframe>" ");

Comment: Now you have to quotes at the beginning...you only need one...try copying exactly what I posted without any additional quotes

Comment: @MrCodingB In the Template literal it should be `<iframe src='https://example.com/embed/${referrerpath}' ...></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You need to use backticks ( ` ) in order to use them.

```js
var referrerpath = document.referrer.replace(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/]+/, '').replace(/#.*/, '').replace(/\?.*/, '');
document.write(`<iframe src='https://example.com/embed/${referrerpath}' style='border:none;width:100%;min-height:400px;'></iframe>`);
```